# QuickTime taking control over AVCHD content?

Tags: macos, finder, quicktime, movie

I've noticed that on 10.8 QuickTime takes control over the AVCHD content folder on my cameras memory card, turning it into a package and requiring you to open it up in QuickTime and convert the videos to mov files.  Is there any way to disable this?  I would much rather have raw access to the .mts files so I can work with them in FCPx.

Thanks!

MacBook Pro 13" Early-2011.  8GB of RAM.  320GB HDD.  OS X 10.8.1.

Comment: Have you tried changing the default application for mts files from an information window?

Comment: ALl I got is VLC.  Quicktime doesn't open MTS files.

Comment: You could also try [editing QuickTime Player's Info.plist](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49447/revert-filetype-association/49740#49740). Does the folder end with something that looks like a filename extension? If it does, `mdls` could give its UTIs.

Comment: I'll try that.  It's a folder on a windows and ubuntu.

Comment: You can still do a secondary-click (right-click or two-finger-click) on the package and select “show package contents” from the contextual menu to access.